# Files generated by TypeScript compiler not recognized as project files in PhpStorm

Tags: javascript, typescript, phpstorm, webstorm

I use PhpStorm 2017.2.3. I don't know if it's an IDE bug, or if I'm doing something wrong but the `.js` files generated by TypeScript compiler are somehow "invisible" as far as the project is concerned.

I have created a separate project to demonstrate this issue in isolation. It contains only 4 files: one JavaScript file added manually (`manually-added.js`), one JavaScript file generated by TypeScript compiler (`typescript-generated.js`), a TypeScript file (`typescript-generated.ts`) and a `tsconfig.json` file with the following configuration:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "module": "commonjs"
  }
}
```

The only thing I have done apart from creating these files was checking *Enable TypeScript Comipler* in PhpStorm *Settings* and pointing it to my `tsconfig.json` file.

And here's how it looks in PhpStorm:

[image]

Note the different icon of `typescript-generated.js` file. It suggests that something is wrong with this file (and this is indeed the case). Here's what:

- It has a different icon as mentioned above.
- You can't use *Mark as Plain Text* on it (if you do nothing happens).
- It is "invisible" to file watchers and scopes.

As you can see scopes and file watchers detect only 3 files instead of 4:

[image]

All suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: Files generated by TS compiler are auto-excluded from project as a result of fixing https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-22318

Comment: @lena So what you're basically saying is: "It's not a bug, it's a feature" ;)

Comment: yes, exactly: it's a feature added at multiple users' requests

Comment: @lena If for some it's a feature and for some a bug, why not make it optional?